# Need to change the default branch on GitHub

Tags: github

I need to change the default branch of my GitHub repository in order to delete it (it was somehow set to default upon uploading a file in which some documents were missing). In other words, I need to upload it again but I can't delete it as is the default...

I don't have the settings option as instructed in the help page. GitHub support never answered my request.

Much thanks for your help
[image: settings image]
[image: repo image]

Comment: Is it your own private repository?

Comment: It is private... It's for a class. I was the one uploading the folder though

Answer (score 0):

First - check to see that you are the **owner** of the repository, or that you have sufficient **permissions**.

1.On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.

2.Under your repository name, click  Settings.

3.In the left menu, click Branches.

4.In the default branch sidebar, choose the new default branch.

> You can only switch between branches that already exist on GitHub.

**EDIT:**

If you are missing the **Settings** button try

1. Ctrl+F5.
2. If that doesn't work clearing the cache and cookies (I'd suggest to just try a different browser).

Comment: Thanks but I do not have the Settings option, that's the problem, even thought I was the one uploading that file.